# How to make underscript format as an underscript in an inline cell?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, formatting, cells, latex

This question maybe a little tiny.

Firstly, let's input underscript <kbd>Ctrl+4</kbd> in an inline cell.

`InlineFormula` inline cell $\underset{n\to\infty}{\text{li}}$

However, if we use $\lim$, we get $\lim_{n\to \infty }$ .

Note: it looks the same in my `Notebook` as `Subscript` by <kbd>Ctrl+-</kbd>   $\lim _{n\to \infty }$

#### TextStyleCell with InlineFormula Inline cells:

---

For clarity, here's the Cell expression:

```
cellExpression = Cell[
    TextData[{
        "subscript: ",
        Cell[BoxData[SubscriptBox["lim",RowBox[{"n","->","\[Infinity]"}]]],"InlineFormula"],
        " underscript: ",
        Cell[BoxData[UnderscriptBox["lim",RowBox[{"n","->","\[Infinity]"}]]],"InlineFormula"]
    }],
    "Text"
];
```

and this is what it looks like in my notebook:

```
CellPrint[cellExpression]
```

> [image]

So how to show $\underset{n\to\infty}{\text{lim}}$ in Notebook's `InlineFormula` cell?

Further, you'll see that when exported to TeX, they are same.

```
StringCases[
    ExportString[cellExpression,"TeX"],
    "\\begin{document}"~~x__~~"\\end{document}" :> StringTrim@x
]


(*
{subscript: \(\lim _{n\text{-$>$}\infty }\) underscript: \(\lim_{n\text{-$>$}\infty }\)}
*)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to do what you want:

First I typeset the desired text cell with an inline equation, then I copy it as a `Cell Expression`:

[image: text]

Make sure that you typeset the limit using `Underscript` and not `Subscript`. It will still show up as a subscript, but we can now change its appearance by appending an option to the `Cell` expression that has been copied above. The popup menu above can only be accessed if you highlight the **cell bracket**, not the text itself.

To modify the limit positioning, I prepared the following code with some blank space into which you now paste the copied cell expression:

[image: paste]

Here, it's important to copy the raw code, so **don't say yes** in the paste dialog that pops up:

[image: paste dialog]

What you get should look something like this:

```
CellPrint[
 Append[Cell[
   TextData[{"This is a text cell with the inline formula ", 
     Cell[BoxData[
       FormBox[RowBox[{RowBox[{UnderscriptBox["lim", 
             RowBox[{"x", "\[Rule]", "0"}]], 
            RowBox[{"f", "(", "x", ")"}]}], "=", "0"}], 
        TraditionalForm]], FormatType -> "TraditionalForm"], "."}], 
   "Text", CellChangeTimes -> {{3.5818712143081923`*^9, 
      3.5818712462119017`*^9}, {3.581872565746663*^9, 
      3.581872576573649*^9}}]

  ,
  UnderscriptBoxOptions ->
   {
    LimitsPositioning ->
     False
    }]
 ]
```

And if you execute this code, the following cell will have the limit typeset in **"display style"**:

[image: display style]

**Edit**

To answer the question in the comment: you can find out which objects are going to be converted to "subscripted" instead of "underscripted" by executing the command

```
Options[Cell, LimitsPositioningTokens]

(*
==> {LimitsPositioningTokens -> {"\[Sum]", "\[Product]", 
   "\[Intersection]", "\[Union]", "\[UnionPlus]", "\[Wedge]", 
   "\[Vee]", "lim", "max", "min", "\[CirclePlus]", "\[CircleMinus]", 
   "\[CircleTimes]", "\[CircleDot]"}}
*)
```

Comment: Hi, Is `limit` so special only? How many keywords like `limit` are so special?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: ha, Good to know about that, so we can also add user defined Symbols?

Comment: Yes, that's right. According to the docs, this option may be subject to change, though. So better use sparingly.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to fix this is to adjust the stylesheet so that inline cells have script level 0.

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData["InlineCell"], ScriptLevel->0, FontFamily->"Times"]
        },
        StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ]
]
```

I threw in a [`FontFamily`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FontFamily) spec because I think it looks better. At any rate, here is a what a text cell with an inline cell looks like with this stylesheet:

[image]