# preventing TraditionalForm from getting "squished"

Tags: front-end, grid-layouts, traditional-form

`TraditionalForm[]` does a great job generally speaking, with complex equations like the following,

```
TraditionalForm[
   Defer[
     1/Pi = 
     2*Sum[((-1)^k*(6*k)!*(13591409 + 545140134*k))/((3*k)!*k!^3*640320^(3*k + 3/2)), {k, 0, 44}]
   ]
]
```

(which is to say…)

[image: pretty equation]

However, if I put this same equation in a `Grid[]` or `Table[]` or `Column[]`, it gets "squished," as in the following

[image: squished]

How can I prevent this from happening? I particularly want to prevent it from swinging the upper bound of the summation to the right of the sigma.

Comment: In LaTeX, these are called display style and inline style.  I don't know (couldn't find) how to control it in Mathematica, but I thought it might be helpful to mention these terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer inspired by [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28010/5467) :

```
Style[Grid[{{TraditionalForm[
     Defer[1/Pi = 
       2*Sum[((-1)^k*(6*k)!*(13591409 + 545140134*k))/((3*k)!*
            k!^3*640320^(3*k + 3/2)), {k, 0, 44}]]]}}], 
 UnderoverscriptBoxOptions -> {LimitsPositioning -> False}]
```

gives :

[image]

**EDIT**

Rojo's solution (see comments) is better because it doesn't reduce the sigma :

```
Grid[{{ TraditionalForm[Defer[1/Pi = 
       2*Sum[((-1)^k*(6*k)!*(13591409 + 545140134*k))/((3*k)!*
            k!^3*640320^(3*k + 3/2)), {k, 0, 44}]]] }}, 
  AllowScriptLevelChange -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Almost there (+1), but the size of the $\sum$ is still reduced.

Comment: @Szabolcs you'd prefer `GridBoxOptions -> {AllowScriptLevelChange -> False}` instead?

Comment: I edited your answer a bit to simplify how the option is given, please verify!

Comment: @Szabolcs Verified : OK, it works (!)

Answer (score 4):

The key option here is `LimitsPositioning`.

This is an option of `UnderoverscriptBox` and related boxes which determines how under and overscripts of "∑", "∏", "⋂", "⋃", "⊎", "⋀", "⋁", "lim", "max", "min", "⊕", "⊖", "⊗", "⊙" behave when displayed in a display formula or an inlined equation.

You can set them in Mathematica typesetting (box) language, but it can also be set in the Option Inspector (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>). You need to set `LimitsPositioning -> False` in

```
Formatting Options > Expression Formatting > Specific Box Options > UnderoverscriptBoxOptions.
```

You can do that either for the selected notebook or as a (semi) permanent Frontend setting.

Programmatically, this can be realized as follows:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, UnderoverscriptBoxOptions -> {LimitsPositioning -> False}]
```

(global setting, for the duration of your session)

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, UnderoverscriptBoxOptions -> {LimitsPositioning -> False}]
```

(global, permanent setting)

Comment: What I'm struggling to understand is why we seem to need a `Grid` around the expression for it to react to "LimitsPositioning". Without the Grid I can't get it to react to "True". Any ideas?

Comment: There must be more to it than `LimitsPositioning`.  The size of the operator ($\sum$) is also reduced.  It behaves the same way as LaTeX, and we're looking for the equivalent of `\displaystyle` ...

Comment: @rojo The inline style  is only applied in cramped spaces, so if you're not in such a condition the setting of the option doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @Szabolcs Isn't that the `AllowScriptLevelChange` option that's controlling that? It's in GridBoxOptions and other box option settings.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yes, that's it, thank you! (Also to Rojo.)  If you give that option to Grid, it's not even necessary to use LimitsPositioning -> False any more.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am really getting at the question here, but:

```
expr = Defer[
  1/Pi = 2*Sum[((-1)^k*(6*k)!*(13591409 + 545140134*k))/((3*k)!*
        k!^3*640320^(3*k + 3/2)), {k, 0, 44}]]

Grid[{{TraditionalForm@expr}}, ItemStyle-> Directive["DisplayFormula",
       FontFamily-> "Times", FontColor-> Black]]
```

[image]

Comment: Something funny going on with $\frac{1}{\pi}$...

Comment: there is indeed... :(

Comment: `Grid[{{1/P}}] // TraditionalForm` something with `FractionBox` I suspect