# Forcing Mathematica to typeset parentheses

Tags: formatting

I use the definitions from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40796/preventing-traditionalform-from-getting-squished) to typeset formulas in lecture slides. This is my function definition:

```
Attributes[equation] = {HoldAll, HoldAllComplete};
equation[eq___] := Panel[TraditionalForm[Style[HoldForm@Defer[eq], 21]]]
```

I also had to set:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,  UnderoverscriptBoxOptions -> {LimitsPositioning -> False}]
```

It works nicely in many cases. For instance:

```
equation[\[ScriptCapitalP][k, "N", \[Rho]] == \[ScriptCapitalP][X <= k] == \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 0\), \(k\)]\(Binomial["\<N\>", 
 m] \*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Rho]\), \(n\)] \*SuperscriptBox[\((1 - \[Rho])\), \("\<N\>" - n\)]\)\)]
```

[image]

Now, there are some things, the frontend just refuses to typeset, for instance parentheses it considers superfluous. For example, I want to reproduce:

$$
\overline{\left(\frac{X}{y}\right)}_\mathrm{geom}=\frac{\overline{X}_\mathrm{geom}}{\overline{Y}_\mathrm{geom}}
$$

The best I could get was:

```
equation[Subscript[(\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\((\*FractionBox[\(X\), \(Y\)])\), \(_\)]\)), geom] == Subscript[\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(X\), \(_\)]\), geom]/Subscript[\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(Y\), \(_\)]\), geom]]
```

[image]

Any ideas on how to improve?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This sounds like a lot of fiddeling. I still hope there is a more generic way :)

Answer (score 7):

If you're going to be doing this programmatically (as opposed to typing directly into a Text cell) and doing it often, then perhaps a function that is typeset as parentheses would be useful.

```
Format[parens[e_]] := DisplayForm@RowBox[{"(", MakeBoxes@e, ")"}]

equation[Subscript[OverBar[parens[X/Y]], "geom"] == foo]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

If you need to adjust the space around the expression `e`, an [`AdjustmentBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AdjustmentBox.html) can be used.

```
ClearAll[parens];
Format[parens[e_, opts : OptionsPattern[AdjustmentBox]]] := 
 DisplayForm@RowBox[{"(", AdjustmentBox[MakeBoxes@e, opts], ")"}]

equation[
  Subscript[OverBar[parens[X/Y, BoxMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0.5}}]], "geom"] == foo]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: this is cool. Thanks! Is there a way to control the height of the parentheses? The fraction apears to be somewhat higher.

Comment: @MarkusRoellig Please see update.

Comment: @MichaelE2 +1ed ofc but I have a question. Is `Format` necessary in definition of `parens`? I mean, what does it change because I'm always confused with that formatting functions.

Comment: @Kuba I suppose it's not strictly necessary.  The difference is in what is stored in the kernel, `parens[e]` or `DisplayForm[...]`.  Probably not a big difference in this case, in fact, but I guess I use `Format` for typesetting expressions out of habit.  I suppose using an `InterpretationBox` could be more robust.  One could make a typeset expression that is interpreted as `parens[e]`.  Thanks for the upvote. :)

Comment: Ok, thanks :) some sort of compact comparison whould be useful. I mean: "use Format when, use Interpretation when... and not Format because.". Now there are multiple ways to get the result but beginners or me :P don't know if they are just different but the same or it really matters. p.s. documentation is not compact :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
    StyleBox[
  RowBox[{
    SubscriptBox[
     RowBox[{"(", FractionBox[OverscriptBox["X", "_"], "y"], ")"}], 
     "geom"], "=", 
    FractionBox[SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox["X", "_"], "geom"], 
     SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox["Y", "_"], "geom"]]
          }]
  , SpanMaxSize -> Infinity] // DisplayForm
```

It gives this: [image]
I am not quite sure about the line over the letters. All lines I have seen in the palette are short.

Comment: Thanks Alexei. This is not exactly what I wanted. The overbar is for the whole fraction X/Y, not only the numerator, so it should span the parentheses.

Comment: @Markus Roellig that's right, this was also my point. I did not find the way of doing that. The focus in my answer is the way of stretching the parentheses. This is fixed by the option ´SpanMaxSize -> Infinity´.