# Fractions formatting in Column / Grid

Tags: output-formatting, options, grid-layouts, inheritance

Fractions are squished in `GridBox`:

```
expr = Style["\!\(\*FractionBox[\(\[Alpha]\),\(360 \[Degree]\)]\)", Bold, 30];

{#, Column[{#}]} & @ expr
```

> [image]

But we can fix this with [`AllowScriptLevelChange -> False`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40796/5478) as shown in linked topic.

```
{#, Column[{#}, AllowScriptLevelChange -> False]} &@expr
```

> [image]

---

**The problem is `GridBox` inherits this option** from outer `GridBoxes` **only when it is `True`**! Moreover even if I fix the inner option `AllowScriptLevelChange -> False` it will be overwritten by default `True` from outer one.

```
Grid[{{#, Column[{#}, AllowScriptLevelChange -> False]}}
    ] &@expr
```

> [image]

```
Grid[{{#, Column[{#}]}}, 
     AllowScriptLevelChange -> False] &@expr
```

> [image]

This behaviour is forcing me to manually put this option in each `GridBox`.

```
Grid[{{#, Column[{#}, AllowScriptLevelChange -> False]}}, 
     AllowScriptLevelChange -> False] &@expr
```

> [image]

#### IMO it is a bug.

Comment: Are you are aware that you can change this setting on the Cell, Notebook, or Global level?  I assume that is not what you want.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This is the main problem, option value is not preserved even if you explicitly state it. It makes no sense.

Comment: Let me see if I understand; your primary concern is with a given expression changing when inserted into a `GridBox`, correct?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Let's say your code is producing `Grid` with fractions with `AllowScriptLevelChange -> False` if you pass it to someone and he puts it in his `Grid` structure it will change the appearance. It is not how style should  work.

Comment: I added an `inheritance` tag because I think that grouping issues such as this will eventually be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### A solution for the issue at hand

Based on your comments I believe you are looking for [`ScriptLevel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ScriptLevel.html) itself:

```
expr2 = "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(\[Alpha]\),\(360 \[Degree]\)]\)";
expr2 = Style[expr2, Bold, 30, ScriptLevel -> 0];

Grid[{{#, Column[{#}]}}] & @ expr2
```

[image]

For application at the `Grid`/`Column` level one can use [`ItemStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ItemStyle.html):

```
{#, Grid[{{#, Column[{#}, ItemStyle -> {ScriptLevel -> 0}]}}]} &[1/2]
```

[image]

---

### Behavior of GridBoxOptions

I don't see this as a bug.  There are other explicit `GridBox` options that are also not inherited by inner grid constructs.  For example `GridFrame`:

```
Grid[{{#, Column[{#}]}}, GridFrame -> True] & @ expr
```

[image]
(The inner `Column` is not framed.)

Having such options inherited could itself be troublesome.

For what it's worth `AllowScriptLevelChange` can be controlled at the Cell, Notebook, or Global level via `"GridBoxOptions"`.  For example:

```
print = CellPrint @ 
    Cell[BoxData @ ToBoxes @ #, "Output", 
     "GridBoxOptions" -> {AllowScriptLevelChange -> False}] &;

Grid[{{#, Column[{#}]}}] & @ expr // print
```

[image]

Comment: For the record: `ItemStyle` solution provides the behaviour I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

`ScriptMinSize` behaves well with respect to inheritance, so one work-around is to add it:

```
{#, Grid[{{#, Column[{#}, BaseStyle -> {ScriptMinSize -> 30}]}}]} & @ expr
```

[image]

It is still not the same and still inconvenient but sufficient for my purposes.