# Control size of formula in a gridbox

Tags: size

When I enter a multi-line formula, I always use a gridbox. But I find that the size of formula in each box is not appropriate. For example, when I enter a compound formula containing fraction or complicated symbol of summation and integration, the size of these will be much smaller than a single line formula.

Comment: Could you provide your code showing this?

Comment: I believe this question is a duplicate of: [(47746)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47746/121) -- please review that Q&A a let me know if it solves your problem.  If not please explain further.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. Your refferences solve my problem exactly.

Comment: Alright.  Make sure you see both: [(40796)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40796/121), [(47746)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47746/121)