# How do I under/overset limits of Sum in text

Tags: front-end, formatting, cells

In the front end, in a cell whose style is "Text", how do I typeset Sum so that the limits are literally above and below the sum symbol?

I keep getting this, even when I click on the underset using the "Basic Typesetting" palette:

[image]

But I want:

$$\sum_x$$

An answer where I have to directly edit the cell expression using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> on PC) is perfectly fine.

Comment: Duplicate: [(112075)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/112075). Related: [(40796)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40796)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set [`LimitsPositioning -> False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LimitsPositioning.html) in [`UnderoverscriptBoxOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnderoverscriptBoxOptions.html) in your `"Text"` cell through the Options Inspector. Just search for "LimitsPositioning" and click on `False` in the drop-down menu.  (This could be added to the stylesheet instead.)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also add `LimitsPositioning -> False` directly to the `UnderoverscriptBox` in the cell expression.