# If Row & Column are used together, why does the appearance of the formula change?

Tags: formla-expression

I expressed the expression of the formula for the limit as a string.

```
PasteButton[Style["\!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(\[Limit]\), \(n \[Rule] \\[Infinity]\)]\)f[n]", 12], Unevaluated[Limit[SelectionPlaceholder[expr], Placeholder[var] -> Placeholder[value]]], ImageSize -> {70, 35}, BaselinePosition -> Center]
```

[image]

I need to insert this inside Column & Row.

```
Column[{Row[{PasteButton[ Style["\!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(\[Limit]\), \(n \[Rule] \\[Infinity]\)]\)f[n]", 12],   
 Unevaluated[ Limit[SelectionPlaceholder[expr], Placeholder[var] -> Placeholder[value]]], ImageSize -> {70, 35},            BaselinePosition -> Center]}]}]
```

[image]

In this case, the form of the equation is not natural. Is there a way to express it as well as in the first place?

Comment: Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28010/1871

Comment: Thank you. I'll refer to it.